# FUSE open system call mechanism

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse

When calling to the `open` system call from a program, to create an empty file (with `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`) in a FUSE managed directory, the following functions from my FUSE file system implementation are executed:

1. `getattr` (returns error because file doesn't exist)
2. `create`
3. `fgetattr`

My question is:

*Are these function calls common to all file systems in Linux (including native ones like ext4), or a FUSE internal behaviour?*

When `strace`-ing the program, I can only see an `open` system call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some days spent researching and staring both at Linux kernel and FUSE source code, I understood what was happening.

First, I have to say that the `release` after `fgetattr` wasn't executing when performing the `open` system call, but when calling `close`. So I have edited my question to remove it.

Well, my main problem was that `strace` showed me a call to the `open` system call, but my FUSE program log showed that three functions were executed. Hence my question about other filesystems.

In [Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfs.txt) we can see the kernel VFS explained in detail:

> To look up an inode requires that the VFS calls the lookup() method of
>   the parent directory inode. This method is installed by the specific
>   filesystem implementation that the inode lives in. Once the VFS has
>   the required dentry (and hence the inode), we can do all those boring
>   things like open(2) the file, or stat(2)

That, in FUSE filesystems, means a `lookup` call in low level API, or a `getattr` in the high level API (because inode-path translation is handled by libfuse). Userland code. Other system calls, like `mkdir` or `open` with `O_CREAT` flag, also need a `lookup`, in this case to confirm a *negative dentry* before doing anything. Point 1 resolved.

> The dentry you get should not have an inode (i.e. it should be a negative dentry).

Filesystems implemented into the kernel, like ext4, execute their functions to `lookup` too. But you can't see them from outside with *common* tools like `strace` (you need something like kernelshark, awesome stuff).

See [ext4 lookup function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/namei.c?v=3.13#L1409) (I'm running a Linux 3.13 kernel)

The `fgetattr` function call of point 3 is more related to the libfuse internals. I don't know the exact reason, but a `lookup` is performed by libfuse after executing functions like `mkdir` or `create`. And remember, a `lookup` is a `getattr` (or `fgetattr` for created files) in the high level API. I think it's due to a file/directory attributes checking.

You can see it in action at [libfuse source code](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/lib/fuse.c#L3066) for create function.

Bonus: keep in mind that FUSE uses a file attribute (and entry) cache. Some calls like `stat` will raise two `getattr` to the high level API if you set the `-o attr_timeout` mount option to 0 seconds.